# name 'nltk' is not defined

Tags: nltk

[The nltk module is running with other libraries in the corpus folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC2NV.png)

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2d25.png)

I've already tried putting 'import nltk' at first but it is still the same, and also I've tried 'from nltk.tokenize import 'PunktSentenceTokenizer'. I don't know why the Python shell can't find the definition of the nltk. How should I address this? I am still learning how to write and code python.

Comment: did you install nltk for python 3.7?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install nltk` in the command prompt?

Comment: yes i have tried it

Comment: What happens when you run `python3 <your_script_name>.py`?

Comment: "'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: but when I type 'python' it works, but still the same "name 'nltk' is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

First, install the nltk package by typing...

```
pip install nltk
```

Then you need to import it...

```
import nltk
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the name of the package in your file, you have used `ntlk` instead of `nltk`

change

`tagged = ntlk.pos_tag(words)`

to

`tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)`